# Реализация тега Select

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Подскажите как реализовать выпадающий список.

Вот моя текущая реализация:

```js
$('#sel').change(function() {
  if ($('#sel option:selected').hasClass("sel_1")) {
    $("#result").html("");
  } else if ($("#sel option:selected").hasClass("sel_2")) {
    $("#result").html("");
  } else if ($('#sel option:selected').hasClass("sel_3")) {
    $("#result").html("");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="select_gr">
  <select id="sel">
    <option class="sel_1">Выберите</option>
    <option class="sel_2">ПКС-35</option>
    <option class="sel_3">ТМ-35</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Как мне при нажатии на option в select вывести в result таблицу, и чтобы её можно было стилизовать в css?

Comment: Какую таблицу нужно вывести? Откуда?

Comment: Ну мне её надо создать и и выводить на страницу только при нажатии на ПКС-35.

Comment: Ну так что за таблица? Если вы не знаете как формировать таблицу на основе входных данных, то спрашиваете не о том.

Comment: Там будет таблица с учащимися в группе и их оценки по предметам.

Comment: Тогда точно спрашиваете не о том, определитесь с форматом входных данных и с тем как должна выглядеть таблица, задайте новый вопрос.

Comment: Я понимаю как выглядит таблица, я не могу понять как сделать её вывод при нажатии на option

Comment: Тогда добавьте ее в вопрос

Comment: Таблица БД или HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Логика примерно такая:

```js
$(document).on('change', '#select_gr select[name="faculties"]', function() {
  let cur_fac = $(this).val();
  switch (cur_fac) {
    // здесь, мы посылаем запрос Аяксом в php, 
    // который вернет таблицу
    $.ajax({
      url: '/getTable.php',
      type: 'POST'
      data: {
        fac_number: cur_fac
      }
    }).done(function(res) {
      // после чего вставляем html код в div с id="result"
      $('#result').html(res);
    }).fail(function(res) {
      alert('Произошла ошибка');
      console.log(res);
    })
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="select_gr">
  <form>
    <select name="faculties" requared="">
      <option value="0" disabled="" selected="">Выберите</option>
      <option value="1">ПКС-35</option>
      <option value="2">ТМ-35</option>
    </select>
    
    <input type="submit" value="Отправить"/>
  </form>
</div>

<div id="result"></div>
```